# Filtering a doubly nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

For some particular reasons I have a nested list, e.g.,

```
Dimensions[ourlist]={N,M,3}
```

where the third dimension includes 3 elements: the function, its first and second derivatives. So basically, each entry of the third dimension looks like this:

`{ 1 , {1,1,1} ,{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}} }`

I can't figure out how to delete cases in this nested list (NxMx3) in which the norm of the gradient, i.e. the vector {1,1,1}, is larger than a threshold value. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `Pick`:

```
ourlist = Table[{"f", RandomReal[1, 3], "f''"}, {2}, {5}]



Pick[
 ourlist,
 Map[Norm[#] <= 1. &, ourlist[[All, All, 2]], {2}],
 True
]
```